# check if object is a TypeError

Tags: typescript, jasmine, rxjs

How can I check that an error is a `TypeError` ?
I would like to do something like this :

```
myObservable.subscribe(() => {}, (error) => {
  expect(typeOf error).toEqual('TypeError');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [instanceof type guards](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html)?

```
const val = error instanceof TypeError;
expect(val).toEqual(true);
```